# Double Pendulum Reset

Tags: reinforcement-learning

i am facing a problem concerning the synchronization between gazebo clock and tf time stamp once the service "Reset Simulation" is called.
i am currently working on the double pendulum simulation and noticed that there's an issue with the " Reset Simulation", for it doesn't reset the time stamp of the tf topic.
This causes a desynchronisation between the Gazebo "clock" which resettled to zero after the "Reset Simulation" whereas the tf time stamp remained equal to the last timestep before the reset.

However, this issue is not present in TurtleBot.

Can anyone help me solve this matter ?

[this is what i get when typing in the terminal: rostopic echo /tf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nBbB.png)